# Cannot resolve PowerMockito but can PowerMockRunner

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to use `PowerMockito`, but I faced some difficulties.

This is what I imported in `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

These annotations were added above the test class definition:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestedClass.class)
```

PowerMockRunner was successfully recognized, but when I try to use `PowerMockito` in order to use methods like `PowerMockito.withNew()`, `PowerMockito` is not recognized.

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import also :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**This library contains the API. The one you imported contains only the support for jUnit4.**

Answer (score 2):

You've added only powermock integration with junit4

In order to access `PowerMockito` you have to add it as a separate dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>${your-powermock-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the complete PowerMockito dependencies for maven.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>${your-powermock-version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>${your-powermock-version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are planning to use `PowerMockRule`, then along with the above dependencies, add these also.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
      <version>${your-powermock-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-classloading-objenesis</artifactId>
      <version>${your-powermock-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Happpy PowerMocking !!!